# How can I perform indexing in datagridview in c# .net

Tags: c#-4.0

I want to show only few rows in DataGridview (like 1 to 10) and remaining are shown on button click..
so How can I Perform this operation..

Comment: Do you mean you want to hide them, or that you don't want to load them from the DB?

Comment: it depends on your datasource. are you getting data from SQL Server? if so - your statement needs to be generated there for paging.

Comment: No I wanna hide them for a first view... and then I'll place a button on the form and will show the remaining...I want paging in c# just like Asp.net..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have all data loaded (that means you are not doing paging on DB side for example) then keep track of page;

```
private int page = 0;
protected void ShowNextResults_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      page++;

      dataGridView1.CurrentCell = null; //required to control row visibility as we cannot hide current cell

      int from = page * 10;
      int to = from + 10;

      for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
      {
           if (i >= from || i < to)
           {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = true;
           }
           else
           {
                dataGridView1.Rows[i].Visible = false;
           }
      }
}
```

This traverse results forward but it should be very easy to implement backwards moving.